# Where does react's typing for InputHTMLAttributes' value: ReadonlyArray<string> come from?

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, input, types

In React's typings the value attribute for Input (InputHTMLAttributes) is defined as

```
value?: string | ReadonlyArray<string> | number | undefined;
```

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L2302

What type of input is the readonly array used for?
And why is it readonly specifically?